# Does python have header files like C/C++?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Does python require header files like C/C++ ?
What are the differences between including header files and importing packages ?

Comment: nope you do not if you write python

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, Python does not have header files nor similar.  Neither does Java, despite your implication that it does.

Instead, we use "docstrings" in Python to make it easier to find and use our interfaces (with the built-in `help()` function).

Answer (score 5):

no you dont have to... in some cases you would want to import libraries..http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm