# Header files in python

Tags: python, header-files

How do I create a header file in `python` ?
I know the steps to do it in `C++` but I don't know how to do it in python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does python have header files like C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764091/does-python-have-header-files-like-c-c)

Comment: you shouyld look into python and pakages

Comment: Why do you think you need a header file? If you explain why you're trying to make a header file, we can explain what you actually need to do instead.

Comment: See also: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

- create a new python file (e.g.: `pseudo_header`) here you can add function, variables etc.

  Example - in `pseudo_header`:

  ```
  name = "Bob"
  ```
- in your `main.py` do this:

  ```
  import pseudo_header
  print(pseudo_header.name) << "Bob"
  pseudo_header.name = "John"
  print(pseudo_header.name) << "John"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Python is not having header files like c++. Instead we import libraries here.

For example take below small piece of code.

```
import datetime

print datetime.datetime.now()
```

Output

```
2019-11-15 12:33:33.177000
```

Here we are importing library datetime. datetime.datetime.now() will give you the current date. 
You can also import only a specific object instead of whole module. Like below.

```
from datetime import datetime

print datetime.now()
```

Comment: Please elaborate. Provide examples. Simple questions are opportunities. In this case to breliefly explain namespaces and point the OP to the appropriate info

Comment: @pynchia agreed.

Comment: This question is on SO already (see the comment above) but the answers aren't very satisfactory

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to define anything before code in python as we did in c++.

You just know about the syntax of the python it will be enough for beginner programming.

But if you want to use some extra libraries then you will need some importing.

**Example**

```
print("Hello World")

output
>> Hello World
```

Similarly you can ***define variables***, do some ***conditional programming*** or define some ***loops*** etc.

**Example**

```
a = 5
if a != 5:
   print("I am angry")
if a == 5:
   print("I am happy")

output
>> I am happy
```

See there is no need to do any importing.

But if you want to use some libraries like. **DateTime**

```
import datetime

print datetime.datetime.now()
```

This library deals with date and time and anythings belongs to them.

That is python :)

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is create a separate library file with all function definitions and import this in the main script.

Let's say my library is called `foo.py`, which contains

```
import numpy as np

def side(area):
    '''
    Function to get length of the side of a square of a given area.
    '''
    assert (area > 0), 'Invalid input!'
    return np.sqrt(area)
```

Then, in my main script, I just import the library and use the functions.

```
import numpy as np
from foo import *

area = 100
print (side(area)) # returns 10
```

May not be the best way but works for me.